# User defined class in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-class

Is it possible to define "user's" class in css?

fot example:

> customClass = div > a

And use it as selector:

```
.customClass: hover {
  //some styles
}

.customClass > span {
  //some styles
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not with standard CSS.

**[LESS](http://lesscss.org/)** may have this ability though:

http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 0):

Check out CSS compilers like:

- [Less](http://lesscss.org)
- [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)